# How to create visible (FLS and in all Layouts) custom field via API

Tags: api, metadata, tooling

When I create a custom field via Tooling API

`post '{"Metadata":{"type":"Number","description":"test","inlineHelpText":"","precision":10,"scale":5,"required":false,"label":"SomeField"},"FullName":"Lead.SomeField__c"}' to /sobjects/CustomField`

I cannot use it due to FLS and its not visible to me in page layout.
I need your help how do it properly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real magic to it. You must create all of the other metadata changes that you expect to have happen.

For Layouts, you'd have to pull the existing Layout metadata, make changes to it to add your new field in the desired position, and then redeploy it. You can do this using the [Apex Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_supported_types.htm), if desired, or use the Tooling or Metadata APIs.

For FLS, you'd similarly need to make changes to either Profiles or Permission Sets to grant FLS to this field, or add a new Permission Set that exposes it and provide a Permission Set Assignment to the relevant users. You can build Permission Sets in Apex, if desired, or likewise use the Tooling or Metadata APIs.